# How to put a newline in ant property

Tags: java, ant

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<property name="foo" value="\n bar \n"/>
```

I use the property value in the body of an e-mail message (which is sent as plain text):

```
<mail ...>
  <message>some text${foo}</message>
```

and I get literal "\n" in the e-mail output.

Comment: It's XML so try using &#10; for a newline.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

These all work for me:

```
<property name="foo" value="bar${line.separator}bazz"/>

<property name="foo">bar
bazz2</property>

<property name="foo" value="bar&#10;bazz"/>
```

Comment: Not directly related but the ReplaceRegExp task only allowed me to use the XML characters to replace. ${line.separator} only worked when put in the beginning.

Answer (score 20):

You want `${line.separator}`.  See [this post](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/05/ant-multi-line-messageecho.html) for an example.  Also, the Ant [echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) manual page has an example using `${line.separator}`.

By using `${line.separator}` you're simply using a Java system property.  You can read up on the list of system properties [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), and [here is Ant's manual page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) on Properties.

Comment: Note that `${line.separator}` is platform specific, therefore the build become platform dependent.

Comment: @RobertHume No it wouldn't. OP is sending an e-mail using Ant's [mail task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) and is using the newline in the e-mail message. Referencing `${line.separator}` will not change the output of the build.

Comment: Right, in this case there's no risk. Thanks!

Comment: I'm developing in windows and my build outputs generates a "run.sh" for linux users. By using this ${line.separator} the build always outputs \r\n as line separators, making the .sh script unusable.

Comment: @Gustavo, `${line.separator}` is a system property. You tried to use the system property from one system to create something for another system.  Since you know your target system you can hardcode the desired separator...there was no need for you to use `${line.separator}`.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I didn't notice the "&#10;". This is exactly what I was looking for.